C# Load all assemblies from encrypted zip package and run the app from package using runner app
I have a requirement where I am writing C# console app; which is a runner app; which downloads the encrypted zip package from provide url (and has an entry assembly info and includes all files required to run that package app).

I have to download and store encrypted zip package somewhere in temp (done)
I have to unzip the package in memory (done)

Now, I have to load those assemblies in memory and have to run the app with entry point inforation (dotnet xyz.dll) without storing any of the package files anywhere on the disk...
Is this possible?
using Lorikeet.Core.Extensions;

namespace Runner
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDictionary<string, byte[]> data = new FileInfo(@"2024.05.03.1142.zip").SharpUnzip();

            // Here I get all 71 files including "xyz.dll"
            // To Do ... ?? ... What's next I should do?
        }
    }
}

Note 1: encrypted zip package app is written fully using Dependency Injection so it should resolve all the assemblies it requires which are also part of the package.
Note 2: I have to make this work on .net8.0 and requirement is to be able to run on Windows, Mac and Linux.

The .NET Framework included a method on the AppDomain class that managed resolving Assembly instances (Assemblies are abstracted DLLs (possibly with other artifacts)). But .NET Core does include AppDomains. If it were me, I'd start with building your "runner" to load a single Assembly into memory (just from the file system) and get it to run. Then I'd figure out how to manage resolving an additional Assembly. Then add in the ZIP part, then go whole hog. My advice is not to start with a 71 file ZIP package
